# Testing CPU Scheduling

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, queue, cpu, scheduling

How can I test a CPU scheduling algorithm (example:RR)?
As you know, an operating system includes its own processes which run on the CPU. However, I want to do it in a pure environment without any other processes and just with the P1, P2, and P3 processes that I have made.

Is there any simulation environment for testing CPU scheduling algorithms?

Edited:PART 1 : For example a company like Microsoft or in Universites how test the CPU scheduling algorithms and see it's result? I want to see that result.

PART 2 : Is there any simulation environment for doing this?
when we have OS (Windows,Linux) so there are some processes which blongs the OS.but I want to do it in a pure environment.

I don't know my idea is right or No,please tell if I'm making mistake for testing the CPU scheduling algorithm.
How can I implement it?
because I had just do it in a paper.

Comment: I think this is not exactly related with the OS, but with the driver. At the Linux ecosystem, for example, AMDGPU kernel driver (this is a new driver for AMD GPU, the old one already has scheduling support implemented) has started to receive only now this support. That's why I'm inferring this is driver related, not OS specific. But I may be wrong (source of the AMDGPU info: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMDGPU-GPU-Scheduler)

Comment: 'an operating system includes its own processes which run on the CPU' - no, not absolutely required.

Answer (score -1):

The CPU scheduler a.k.a task/process scheduler is inside the kernel for Linux systems. So, one way to compare between two different tasks scheduler is to build the same kernel with two different scheduler and compare with the same workload or application. The default scheduler in Linux is CFS (Complete Fair Scheduler). There are several other schedulers for example, Real-Time, BFS, and others. The RR (Round Robin) is just the method in choosing the next task to be schedule after one task is preempted.
Here is more info about [Tuning the Task Scheduler](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/tuning/html/book.sle.tuning/cha.tuning.taskscheduler.html)

Comment: The link you provided is not working.